# COPYARTIFACT_BUILD_NUMBER_SUFFIX in workflow jobs

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-workflow, jenkins-pipeline

Does the COPYARTIFACT_BUILD_NUMBER_SUFFIX work on expected lines in workflow/pipeline jobs? 
copy artifact command am using is

**step([$class: 'CopyArtifact', filter: '*.rpm', fingerprintArtifacts: true, projectName: 'test_pkg', resultVariableSuffix: 'testsuffix', selector: [$class: 'ParameterizedBuildSelector', parameterName: 'testparam'], target: 'test_packages'])**

when i do

*println COPYARTIFACT_BUILD_NUMBER_TESTSUFFIX*

am getting the below error

*groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: COPYARTIFACT_BUILD_NUMBER_TESTSUFFIX for class: WorkflowScript*

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to check the env instead: `println env.COPYARTIFACT_BUILD_NUMBER_TESTSUFFIX`?

Comment: Hi izzekil, i did try env.COPYARTIFACT_BUILD_NUMBER_TESTSUFFIX?, it returns null :-(

Comment: Not sure what you are expecting this variable to be. I cannot find references to it.

What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Hi Jesse, Let me try to give an example.                                              when we copy artifacts of  say "build #123" of job A into a running build of job b, we need a way to get the build #123 of job A from job B. We are trying to accomplish the above using the above variable. am attaching screen shot from snippet generator to my original post. Kindly  provide your inputs.

Comment: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/plugins/servlet/mobile#issue/JENKINS-34620

Answer (score 3):

I am also having the same problem. What I (and I guess KishorePP too) want to achieve is, to retrieve the BuildNumber from the build that generated the artifacts.

But the environment variable is somehow not existent or differently named. 
The plugin I use is this: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Copy+Artifact+Plugin

As in source Code of https://github.com/jenkinsci/copyartifact-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/hudson/plugins/copyartifact/CopyArtifact.java#L739 we can see that there the Variable is pushed into the env map.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing a printenv in your shell script.